# row.names(df[c(6193,7812),])- How to diplay certain row.names of a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

`row.names(df[c(6193,7812),])`

df is a data.frame that consists of 8000 rows and a row.name column and one additional column.
I want the row.names of df, but only of the 6193rd and 7812th row. Why isn´t this working?

`row.names(df)` works but only displays the row.names until row 1000 because then R reaches the maximal print.

`View(df[c(6193,7812), ]` is not working either…. It only shows the first column, but not the row.names.

For playing around:
`df <- data.frame("col1"=c("1","2","5","5","6"),row.names = c("row1","row2","row3","row4","row5"))`
I feel like it has something to do with the fact that df does not have numbered rows (as row.names). I do not know why and how to change that.

Comment: `rownames(df)[c(2,5)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
row.names(df[c(6193,7812),,drop = FALSE])
```

When you have only one column in the data it drops its attributes by default.

```
df[c(2, 3),]
#[1] "2" "5"
```

and there is no rownames for it.

```
rownames(df[c(2, 3),])
#NULL
```

If you use

```
df[c(2, 3),, drop = FALSE]

#     col1
#row2    2
#row3    5
```

it maintains the attributes and rownames can be found.

```
rownames(df[c(2, 3),, drop = FALSE])
#[1] "row2" "row3"
```